# Probability of Guessing a Code

Tags: probability

A bit stuck trying to work out the probability of something. Assume there is a code with two letters and eight numbers, which is of the following format AADDDDDDDD. Id like to graph the probability of guessing this code over multiple attempts, a hell of a lot of attempts.

I've 'worked out' the answer is the product of this sequence

1 - ( 1 / (676000000001 - x) ), x=1...100000000

Note the -x, far each attempt the chances of guessing the code increase ever so slightly as your pool of possible codes shrinks by one.

This gives me the probability of not guessing it, so I just minus this from one. But my problem is I cant find a program that can work out the answer of this for me, wolfram alpha complains that it keeps running out of computational time, even in the pro version.

Is there anyway I can figure this out without having to find the product of a massive series?

Edit: Answer # of guesses / 676000000000, clearly I am in the mood to over engineer this morning. (facepalm)

Comment: I think you're working too hard. There are $N$ possible codes. If you take $k$ guesses, the chances that one of them is right would be $k/N$.

Comment: You really need to be much clearer so one can support you: Two letters out of which alphabet set? Two numbers of which type (integer?) and set? The selection process of the number follows what type of stochastic? Then how do you derive your formula? what do you mean by "product of this sequence" (write it out please?) how is $x$ defined? what do you mean by the "pool"? I am working with such sequence but can not understand what you mind.

Comment: Gerry is right, ive totally over engineered this.

Comment: To connect the two approaches, the product can be expressed as $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{n-i-1}{n-i}$, where $n$ is the number of possibilities and $k$ the number of distinct guesses.  If you expand this, it looks like $\frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{n-k}{n-k+1}$, which "telescopes" to $\frac{n-k}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

i had a question like this in my math quiz. and let me tell you it sucks.
start off by finding how many letters you need, then numbers.
my question was two letters and two numbers.

there are 26 letters in the alphabet.

26x26= 676
and 10 numbers on a keypad.
10x10=100
now my problem was that i added those two together. multiply the two denominators 100x676= 67600

your answer would be 1/67600
and that's only two numbers and letters, whenever another number is added its time-sing the number count 100 by 10
for the letters every letter is another 26 to multiply.
for three letters it would be
26x26x26= 17576.
and so on. 
(pff my math teacher said i never would understand it but writing my thoughts out on here really helped.) note for future reference always write down your thoughts it will take longer sometimes but will clear your head to think of other things. lol sorry for rambling i am not a very strong typer so i have to get a ton of practice.

Comment: Please consider using correct punctuation and capital letters at the beginning of sentences. That would make your pose much more readable.